# Can frictional force accelerate (speed up) a body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, work

I think since $F=ma$ thus the frictional force can produce acceleration in a body in some cases, is my view correct?please suggest some example then. If not then where i went wrong?

Comment: You know that friction can reduce the speed of a body, don't you?
If the speed changes, you have an acceleration.

Comment: i m not talking about deacceleration  i have used the term accelerate.maybe its my fault, i should have mentioned it earlier.

Comment: In common language acceleration means an object speeds up, but in physics acceleration is any change (faster *or* slower) in velocity over time. Yes, friction can produce acceleration of an object-- it can slow it down.

Comment: so i should ask "can friction speed up a body??"

Comment: Yes that would make it clear what your question is. You can edit your post/title rather than making a new post.

Comment: Yes it can. $\Sigma F = m a$ means sum of forces = mass * acceleration, in that sum, one typically includes friction.

Comment: can you provide an example of situation to make it clear properly??

Comment: does a wheel-based tennis-ball serving machine rely on friction to increase the speed of an object ("positive acceleration")?

Comment: Ever drop an object onto a moving conveyor belt?

Comment: i didn't get you "Yorik"

Comment: how would friction accelerate it??  "dmckee"

Comment: @Qmechanic,Shouldn't it be reopened.Cuz i don't see any answer of my question at the question u have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The F in F=ma isn't required to be a frictional force, it's just any force.

If we assume a frictional force, then in physics-language yes, it does cause an acceleration, but in the opposite direction to motion. An object travelling from left to right and slowing down **is** accelerating, but to the left...for example, if the force slowing it down was a rocket then it would slow, stop, then (in everyday-language) accelerate to the left. In physics language it's **always** accelerating to the left, even when slowing down or stationary.

Frictional forces generally depend on the relative motions of the two objects involved though, so in your specific case when the relative speeds drop to zero the frictional force drops to zero and the acceleration stops, rather than continuing in style of the rocket example.

Comment: "when the relative speeds drop to zero the frictional force drops to zero" what about static friction?

Comment: Static friction would be applicable if you were still applying a force to the object, but we're not in this context.